# Generating Array or Struct in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

Im Expecting some functionality like below,

select  ARRAY((select distinct Somecolumn from Dataset.tablename) )

select  STRUCT((select distinct Somecolumn from Dataset.tablename) )

Comment: Is there a question here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use array_agg function to generate an array, but generating struct is not possible.

```
select ARRAY_AGG(distinct Somecolumn) from Dataset.tablename
```